# How to use netstat to view a list of active TCP and UDP connections and count them?

Tags: networking, netstat

I want to monitor the number of active TCP and UDP connections using the `netstat` command. I tried to run the following command:

```bash
netstat -a | grep -e tcp -e udp | awk '{print $1,$6}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The output contains listening and non-listening connections, while I want to display only active connections. How can I achieve this using `netstat`?

I am using a Linux-based server.

**Edit:**
The expected output will look similar to this:

```
  21 tcp4 ESTABLISHED
   7 tcp4 LISTEN
   3 tcp46 LISTEN
   8 tcp6 ESTABLISHED
   5 tcp6 LISTEN
   1 udp4 0
  56 udp4 786896
   1 udp46 2097152
   2 udp46 786896
   2 udp6 786896
```

Comment: your grep "trick" could be replaced by using the appropriate `netstat` options: `--tcp` `--udp`.

Comment: also, what's "active connection" in the context of UDP? That's just something that sends packets without even knowing if they ever reach anyone;  there's no such thing, proper, as "UDP connection". It's not a "connection-oriented" protocol!

Comment: Does this help: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001079.htm? What do you mean by "active" - do you mean established? If yes, just `grep ESTABLISHED`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the context of the netstat command, when referring to "active connections" for UDP, it generally means the active UDP endpoints.

Comment: so any non-listening UDP socket?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, including non-listening UDP sockets as well.